# Five points in a disk

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, complex-analysis

Why is
$$
\min_{1\le i,j,k\le5}\frac{\mbox{Area}\left(\triangle  P_{i}P_{j}P_{k}\right)}{\mbox{Perimeter}\left(\triangle P_{i}P_{j}P_{k}\right)}<\frac{4}{25}
$$ for any five points $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$, $P_{3}$, $P_{4}$ and $P_{5}$ in the unit disk?
Thanks in advance for any helpful answers!

Comment: Of course you mean $P_n = \exp(2 i \frac{n\pi}{5})$

Comment: If there are not, how to show that this min is always less than $4/25$ for any five points in the unit disk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the area is quadratic in length and the perimeter is linear, you want as big a triangle as possible.  The natural points are a regular pentagon on the circle, so $P_n=\exp (i\frac {2n \pi}5)$.  I find the ratio about $0.15$ for the triangle with two sides of the pentagon and $0.21$ for the triangle with two diagonals.  It seems unlikely that you can do better, but I don't have an easy proof.

Comment: I get the area/perimeter ratios to be $(\sqrt{5}-1)/8 \approx .1545084971$ and $(3 \sqrt{5}-5)/8 \approx .2135254914$ for those two triangles.

Comment: Even an equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit circle has ratio only $1/4$.  I'm pretty sure this is the largest such ratio for any triangle in the unit disk.

Comment: Robert, you are right. It should be 4/25 in my question. But do you know why the min is always less than 4/25 for any five points in the unit disk? Thanks.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I had my 72's and 108's confused.   Thanks

Comment: Ross, if you don't have an easy proof, do you have a hard proof? Thanks!

Comment: @Joia:  no.  I think you could claim the points need to be on the circumference and find the minimum span of three in a row (with the middle one in the center-that is "obviously" the best) that meets $0.16$, observe that it exceeds $144^\circ$, so the pidgeonhole principle says there are three points too close together

Comment: Ross, what do you mean by "the minimum span of three in a row ", and why do they need to be on the circumference? Thanks.

Comment: @Joia:  my only reason for believing they have to be on the perimeter is the dimensional one-as triangles get larger the area/perimeter ration rises.  The minimum span would be the angle between the outer two of three points.  The area calculation done here shows it is greater than $144^\circ$.  Putting five points around the circle will force you to have three in a row that are closer than that.